# PYTHONPATH environment variable - default vs anaconda

Tags: python

I installed python on my PC and working with VS Code. When I checked my `PYTHONPATH` (in VS Code settings), I see this:
`"/Users/<name>/anaconda3/bin/python"`.

I've been looking into many python tutorials (on youtube) and in their steps, when they set the `PYTHONPATH` they get it from `sys.executable` which looks like this:
`"/usr/local/bin/python3"`.

My questions are:

1. What is the difference between the two?
2. What are the pros and cons of each of the above setting?

Comment: not much difference, apart from package maintain by anaconda and pypi, in term of installation. But with default, you dont need to maintain software like anaconda, it will be only python not other fancy thing which anaconda bring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install Python directly from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/), your PYTHONPATH is going to look something like `/usr/local/bin/python3`. If you install Anaconda instead, then Python will come with it, and its PYTHONPATH will look like `/Users/<name>/anaconda3/bin/python`.

There is practically no difference between these two Python installations *per se*, but using Anaconda makes installations easier to manage. Especially if you will use other tools available in Anaconda environment.